# MS ACCESS : Delete operation fails after 100 records

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2016

I'm running into an issue with MS Access. I have a delete routine setup (SQL) that purges an entire table before it's reloaded.  For some reason, when it hits 100 deleted records, it bombs with the following error:

> 3027 - Cannot update. Database or object is read-only.

I've tried all different types of delete methods with the same outcome.

MS ACCESS is 2016 and only recently started to happen. Has anyone seen anything similar? The code I'm using is very simple :

```
    strStep = "Step 1 : Purge Table"
    strSQL = "" & _
            "DELETE [Name_List].* FROM [Name_List]"
    db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```

If I highlight the whole table manually and press delete, it works.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like data corruption. Try to recreate the table from scratch.

Comment: Agree, sounds like some sort of corruption. Posted code appears correct. Although, probably won't make difference, but it is not necessary to reference fields in a DELETE action.

Comment: How often have you deleted the contents of that table already? Compact and repair might solve this.

Comment: Indeed, if such things happen sporadically (works for less than 100 records, throws a seemingly nonsensical error for more), that's almost always an indication of database corruption. Frequent "compact and repair" is your friend if you use MS Access for data storage.

Comment: Hi All - so I deleted the list and rebuilt it but getting the same error. I ran 'Compact and Repair' multiple times as well to no avail.  This is getting very frustrating.  I'll keep pulling back the covers. 

To an earlier question, this routine has been running for 1+ years without issue until recently.

Answer (score -2):

The error message "3027 - Cannot update. Database or object is read-only" typically indicates that the Access database or the specific table you're trying to modify is in a read-only state. There could be several reasons for this issue. Here are some steps you can take to troubleshoot and potentially resolve the problem:

**Check File Permissions:**
Ensure that the folder where the Access database is located has the necessary write permissions for the user account under which Access is running.
Make sure the Access database file itself is not marked as read-only. Right-click the file in Windows Explorer, go to Properties, and make sure the "Read-only" attribute is unchecked.

**Check Database Permissions:**
Confirm that your user account has appropriate permissions to modify the database. You might need to check with your database administrator or IT department if the database is hosted on a network.

**Compact and Repair Database:**
Occasionally, Access databases can become corrupted or experience issues. Try compacting and repairing the database to see if that resolves the problem. To do this, go to the "Database Tools" tab and select "Compact & Repair Database."

**Check for Linked Tables:**
If the table you're trying to delete from is a linked table, make sure that the source database is not read-only or locked by another user.

**Check for Table Locks:**
Ensure that no other users or processes are accessing the table simultaneously, which might lock it.

**Database Splitting:**
If your Access database is a front-end connected to a back-end database (often used in multi-user scenarios), make sure that the back-end database is not set to read-only.

**Virus or Backup Software:**
Sometimes, antivirus or backup software can lock database files. Ensure that no such software is interfering with your database.

**Database Corruption:**
If none of the above solutions work, there may be some level of database corruption. In such cases, it might be necessary to restore from a backup or create a new database and import your objects (tables, queries, forms, etc.) into the new database.

**Access Version and Updates:**
Ensure that your MS Access software is up to date with the latest service packs and updates. Sometimes, issues like this can be resolved with software updates.
Compact and Repair before Delete:

You can try running the Compact & Repair Database operation before running the DELETE query to see if it makes a difference.
If the issue persists after trying these steps, it might be beneficial to involve an IT professional or database administrator to further diagnose and address the problem, especially if it's occurring in a networked or multi-user environment.